# Finding a path in python?

Tags: python

Hello everyone: I have this problem right here given a dictionary named Path and a list of strings named Sequence, find the secret strings hidden in the dictionary. The key will be a tuple with the start word and an element of the Sequence, each tuple in the value will represent the next start word and the secret. The first start word will be given and the Sequence moves from the first element to the last. The output should be a list of tuples with the secret of each last start word and the last start word. For example, having:

```py
start_word = "MAGIC"
Sequence = ["the", "pink", "bubblegum"]

Path = {
    ("MAGIC", "the"): [("INSANE", "once"), ("BLUE", "there")],
    ("INSANE", "pink"): [("FRESH", "a"), ("SHOOT", "we")],
    ("BLUE", "pink"): [("GREEN", "was")],
    ("FRESH", "bubblegum"): [("SALT", "deer")],
    ("SHOOT", "bubblegum"): [("PARROT", "died")],
    ("GREEN", "bubblegum"): [("BLUE", "grass")]
}
```

The result should be:

```py
[
    ("once a deer", "SALT"),
    ("once we died", "PARROT"),
    ("there was grass", "BLUE"),
]
```

Because "MAGIC", "the" has inside "INSANE", "once", so I have to look for "INSANE", "pink" (second word in the sequence), "INSANE", "pink" brings me to "FRESH", "a", and "FRESH", "bubblegum" brings me to "SALT, deer", so "once a deer, SALT" ( I hope it's clear ahah)So, I tried this:

```
key = start_word   
x = 0
for elem in path:
    idk = recursive(path, sequence,key, start_word, x)

def recursive(path, sequence, key, start_word, x):
    for elem in path:
        if x < len(sequence):    
            if elem == (key, sequence[x]):
                for lst in path[elem]:
                    key = lst[0]
                    x += 1
                    secret = secret + lst[1] + " "
                    print(secret)
                    return recursive(path, sequence, key, start_word, x)
        else:
            x, key = 0, start_word
```

But this doesn't give the right secret printed.
If someone has any advice or solution I'd love that. I can't import any libreries.

Comment: I think you can just do a check until you dont find a match, then concat all the second word sequence.

Comment: problem is that I need to concatenate even when the list splits. (For example the word INSANE has two different solutions) So I can't just concat :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, the words are stored into an array and printed at the end. Not sure how you get the second 'once' though.

```
start_word = "MAGIC"
sequence = ["the","pink","bubblegum"]
key = start_word
x = 0

path = {("MAGIC", "the"): [("INSANE", "once"), ("BLUE", "there")], 
        ("INSANE","pink"): [("FRESH", "a"), ("SHOOT", "we")], 
        ("BLUE", "pink"): [("GREEN","was")], 
        ("FRESH","bubblegum"):[("SALT", "deer")], 
        ("SHOOT", "bubblegum"): [("PARROT", "died")], 
        ("GREEN", "bubblegum"):[("BLUE","grass")]}

def recursive(path, sequence, key, start_word, x, array):
    for elem, v in path.items():
        if x >= len(sequence):
            return
        if (elem[0] == start_word) and (elem[1] == sequence[x]):
            x += 1
            for elem1 in v:
                array.append(elem1[1])
                recursive(path, sequence, elem1[1], elem1[0], x, array)

array = []
recursive(path, sequence, key, start_word, x, array)
print(array)
```

Comment: Just read again what you wrote, the solution is almost perfect but the second "once" comes from ("INSANE", "once"), because that tuple actually brings to two different words (both the values of ("INSANE", "pink")). The output is also in the wrong format but it shouldn't be hard to fix ahah. Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach. I tried to process them as a tree structure.

Let me know if you find this difficult to understand. I have included enough comments to help you understand the processing.

```
Path = {
    ("MAGIC", "the"): [("INSANE", "once"), ("BLUE", "there")],
    ("INSANE", "pink"): [("FRESH", "a"), ("SHOOT", "we")],
    ("BLUE", "pink"): [("GREEN", "was")],
    ("FRESH", "bubblegum"): [("SALT", "deer")],
    ("SHOOT", "bubblegum"): [("PARROT", "died")],
    ("GREEN", "bubblegum"): [("BLUE", "grass")]
}

key1 = [k[0] for k in Path.keys()]
key2 = [k[1] for k in Path.keys()]

word = 'MAGIC'

path_tree = [] #for storing the tree structure of each node
temp = [] #for capturing left and right leaf of a node
result_list = [] #to store final result list
result = '' #to concatenate value strings

#check if word is in keys
idx = key1.index(word) if word in key1 else None

#if not found, stop program
if idx is None:
    print ('No match found')
else:
    #start collecting left and right nodes for the tree
    temp = Path[(word,key2[idx])]

    #first left branch will be 0th element
    path_tree.append([temp[0]])

    #if there is a right branch, then store in next position
    if len(temp) > 1: path_tree.append([temp[1]])
    word = path_tree[0][0][0] #start with word in the left branch

    i = 0 #to keep track of length of tree
    while True:

        #if new word is in keys, process. if not found, concat result
        idx = key1.index(word) if word in key1 else None
        if idx is None:
            #join all values from the list into a string using join
            result = ' '.join([v for x,v in path_tree[i]])

            #keyword from last node in the branch + concat string added to result list
            result_list.append([result,path_tree[i][-1][0]])

            #now move to next branch in the tree
            i +=1
            if i < len(path_tree):
                word = path_tree[i][-1][0] #pick the next word to process
                continue
            else:
                break #if all branches processed, then exit the loop
        else:
            #start collecting left and right nodes for the tree
            temp = Path[(word,key2[idx])]

            #check if key already in the branch. If yes, then force out with word = '#'
            a = [k for k,v in path_tree[i] if k == word]
            if len(a) > 1:
                word = '#'
                continue
            else:
                #if word is not in the branch, then add it to the branch
                #if there are two nodes (left & right),
                #then capture info of right, you will process it next
                #modify left to include new info and continue processing
                if len(temp) > 1:
                    path_tree.insert(i+1,path_tree[i] + [temp[1]])
                path_tree[i] = path_tree[i] + [temp[0]]
            #update word to reflect new word from values left node
            word = temp[0][0]

            #continue processing until all branches are processed

#once all branches are processed, you can print the result
if result_list:
    print (result_list)
```

The output is as follows :

For word = `MAGIC`

```
[['once a deer', 'SALT'], ['once we died', 'PARROT'], ['there was grass', 'BLUE']]
```

For word = `INSANE`

```
[['a deer', 'SALT'], ['we died', 'PARROT']]
```

For word = `BLUE`

```
[['was grass was', 'GREEN']]
```

This one has an additional `was` in the end. I need to figure out a way to eliminate that.

Same problem for `GREEN`

```
[['grass was grass', 'BLUE']]
```

For word : `SHOOT`

```
[['died', 'PARROT']]
```

For word : `RANDOM`

```
No match found
```